# Calculate looping through dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, loops, jupyter-notebook

I have the following piece of code.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'c1': [10, 11, 12], 'c2': [100, 110, 120]})
print(df)

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    df['c3'][index] = df['c1'][index] + df['c2'][index]
    print(df['c1'][index], df['c2'][index], df['c3'][index])

print(df)
```

What I want to do is loop through the dataframe and add a third column that has the sum of the columns of the other two. The end result shoud look like this.

```
   c1   c2  c3
0  10  100  110
1  11  110  121
2  12  120  132
```

At the moment I get the problem `KeyError: 'c3'`

How can I implement what I want?

Comment: `df["c3"] = df.sum(1)`

Comment: That returns 330, 363 and 396. Which is wrong. Is there a way to do it specifying the columns like on the example?

Comment: You can do: `df["c3"] = df[["c1", "c2"]].sum(1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do as below:

```
df["c3"]=df["c1"]+df["c2"]
```

Comment: As a follow up to this, on my loop I make a calculus and then transform it to days with `datetime.timedelta(calculus)` but I get a TypeError `TypeError: unsupported type for timedelta days component: Series`? Any idea on how to go around this?

Comment: Is calculus a dataframe or a serie?

Comment: Inside the loop I get the value from a row in a certain column and another value from another column then I do this `datetime.timedelta((1/freq)*days[1])` and then I sum this result the value of a column in a new column. Therefore calculus is a series I think because days[1] is an int but freq changes in every row.

Comment: Actually I don't know hot to do. Sorry :(

Comment: I actually found out by try and error. It is `datetime.timedelta((1/freq[index])*days[1])` 
Thanks!